# Flutter: Help in creation of an app that detects the user's handwriting and turns it into text

Tags: flutter

So, I have been at this project for a while now but I just didn't manage to find anything useful to help in the aid of making this app. I am basically just trying to create an app where the user can write something and the app will recognize the handwriting and turn it into text, where there will be a text guesser guessing what the text will be just in case if the user had written it wrong.

Comment: Try to ask questions that are more specific. What information did you try to look for but did not find? What is the actual problem that you are stuck with?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend checking Digital Ink Recognition from ML Kit, seems like it should resolve your problem: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/digital-ink-recognition

Comment: since digital ink recognition is new, I have no idea on how to use it, can you help?